# Volume integral over a bounded region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Class is over now and I am studying for my final and I have a problem with this question on our review sheet. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Question: Find the volume of the region in space bounded by $z=1-x^2-y^2$ and on the sides by the planes x=0, y=0 and x+y=1 and z=0.

I first found the boundaries: $0\le z \le 1-x^2-y^2$ , $0\le y \le 1-x$, and $0\le x \le 1$.

Originally I just then computed the integral $\int\int\int dzdydx$ which gave me the answer of 1/3 however I feel as though I should be using polar coordinates for this question but when I tried that I could not seem to figure out anything that made sense. I might be screwing up the integral when I switch over to polar coordinates. Worst part is our teacher hasn't posted any solutions so I am really shooting in the dark. Again if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You did the limits right in Cartesian coordinates, but we can, as you pointed, do the triple integral by using the Cylindrical coordinates: $$0\leq z\leq 1-x^2-y^2\longrightarrow 0\leq z\leq 1-r^2 $$ since $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Since $$x+y=1\longrightarrow r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)=1\\\ z=0\longrightarrow1=x^2+y^2\longrightarrow r=1$$ so the ranges of changing $r$ would be as: $$r|_{0}^{\frac{1}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}}$$ For $\theta$, we have $$\theta|_{0}^{\pi/2}$$

[image]

Comment: Ok, I got it, however this is a very long process calculation using these constraints for r.  Is there any other technique that is easier? I also tried something just to see but since $y\le 1-x$  I subbed this into the formula for z and ended up with the boundary $0 \le z \le 2x-2x^2$ which from there I then let r: 0 ->1 and integrated z subbing in polar coordinates. Is this allowed or no? I feel this was probably stupid but I did get a clean answer.

Comment: @user68203: Evaluating the triple integral in Cartesian coordinates looks easier. $$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x^2-y^2}dzdydx$$. This is what you did before.

Comment: Set up, and graphics...nice work.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch coordinate systems, I would recommend cylindrical coordinates (r, theta, z).

Then z = 1 - r^2 and the dx dy would become r dr d(theta), you would also need to change your limits of integration. theta would be 0 to pi/2, r from 0 to 1/(sin(theta) + cos(theta)).

Solving in Cartesian coordinates:
$\\
\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_{z=0}^{1-x^2-y^2}dzdydx = \\
\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x} 1 - x^2 - y^2 dydx =\\
\int_{x=0}^1 (1 - x^2)(1 - x) - (1/3)(1 - x)^3 dx =\\
\int_{x=0}^1 (4/3)x^3 - 2x^2 + (2/3) dx = 1/3$

Comment: I understand this but then what would be the limits of integration for r? Also is it just as correct to calculate the answer using Cartesian coordinates or must it be in spherical?

Comment: sorry nvm, I just miss read. you did put the limits of r.

Comment: Yeah, it's not formatted well because I am new here and haven't learned all the formatting tricks yet.  Did this help?

Comment: @user68203 Yes it is correct to just use the Cartesian coordinates.  It is also correct to use the cylindrical coordinates, but seems unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Yes this was helpful however this integral seems to be very complex unless I screwed up. Anyways this is where I learned how to format questions and give detail: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference